# Why are non-environment variables passed to the subshell invoqued by command substitution?

Tags: bash, shell

Bash manual says:

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment,
>   except that traps caught by the shell are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its parent at invocation.

In this example,`b` isn't an environment variable, so `b` doesn't exist in the subshell created by command substitution. Then why is `c` assigned the value of `b` by command substituion? Is it because the parameter expansion happens for `$b` in the shell process before creating a subshell to execute `echo 1`?

```
$ b=1
$ c=$(echo $b)
$ echo $c
1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the subshell was created first.

A [shell execution environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) contains shell parameters set by variable assignments and environment variables. A subshell environment was created by duplicating the shell environment, so it contains all the variables of the current shell environment.

See the example:

```
$ b=1
$ c=$(b=2; echo "$b")
$ echo "$c"
2
```

The output is `2` instead of `1`.

---

A subshell environment created by command substitution is different with a shell environment created by calling the shell executable.

When you call the shell as:

```
$ bash -c :
```

the the current shell used [execve()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) to create new shell process, something like:

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", ":"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
```

the last argument passed to `execve` contains all the environment variables.

That's why you need to [export](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_22) the variables to push it to the environment variables, which will be included in subsequently executed commands:

```
$ a=; export a
$ strace -e execve bash -c :
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", ":"], [/* 65 vars */]) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Notice the environment variables change from 64 to 65. And variables which are not exported will not be passed to new shell environment:

```
$ a=; b=; export a
$ strace -e execve bash -c :
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", ":"], [/* 65 vars */]) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Notice the environment variables are still 65.

---

In command substitution, the shell used [fork()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) to create new shell process, which just copied the current shell environment - which contains both variables set and environment variables.

Comment: rui@ruir:~$ b=1
rui@ruir:~$ bash
rui@ruir:~$ echo $b
(nothing)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: You were confused between child process environment and subshell environment.

Comment: thanks. In my example,b isn't an environment variable, why is c assigned the value of b by command substituion?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the English, and made a word change that I think will help @Tim understand better the issue of his last question.

Comment: @Rui: Does the reply answer my question in my last comment, which is also in my post? I.e. In my example, b isn't an environment variable, so b doesn't exist in the subshell, why is c assigned the value of b by command substituion?

Comment: @Tim: I think I can say with a certain degree I got or assumed cuonglm answer which was/is fine by me. I made a more relevant change to his answer, in the last phrase, for it to give away more clearly that when invoking a subshell, a fork is made with all the variables copies of the current/initial shell (the subshell is an exact copy of the original shell). As cuonglm kindly pointed out, I was making the same assumption as you, mistaking the creation of a child process for a subshell, and he proved me wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you give the definition of a subshell, so as to distinguish from a shell process invoked by running `bash`?

Comment: Also is the case of running a bash script same as running `bash -c <command>`?

Comment: @Tim "is the case or running a bash script same as running `bash -c <command>`". There is a very slight different: When you execute a shell script, the kernel reads the first line, sees the "sh-bang" and tries to execute the program specified after that with the script itself as the first argument. Thus, it's the difference between `bash <scriptfile>` and `bash -c <scriptfile>`. In the second form, bash will do an `exec` with `<scriptfile>` as an argument, and so ultimately, you get `bash <scriptfile>` again, but after an additional exec.

Answer (score 3):

Yes b isn't an environment variable.
But: Yes, b does exist in the subshell created by command substitution:

```
$ b=11; c="$(echo $b)"; echo "$c"          ### b exists in subshell.
11
$ b=11; c="$(b=33; echo $b)"; echo "$c"    ### $b is not replaced before
33                                         ### the subshell is executed.
```

What [does not receive the variables is a "full child process"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell):

```
$ b=11; bash -c 'echo "<$b>"'              ### b does not exist.
<>
$ b=11 bash -c 'echo "<$b>"'               ### environment b.
<11>
```

Except that a process may receive variables in the environment, of course.

---

Last line at [Wooledge SubShell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell):

> In the subshell, the regular shell variable a is visible; but because it is not exported, the full child process does not see it.

Answer (score 2):

Command substitution causes a normal call to the shell interpreter and this interpreter will run the `echo` command in a `sub-process`.

The `sub-process` is needed as the shell needs to establish a `pipe` to the `echo` command in order to be able to read the results.

The `sub-process` that runs the `echo` command is created by `fork()` and this creates copies of all variables from the main shell process. This is why `$b` is accessible by the `echo` command.