# What differences are between running a command in shell with and without `bash -c`?

Tags: linux, bash, exec, fork, strace

What is the difference of running a command directly in a bash shell, and run it as `bash -c <command>` in a bash shell?
The purpose of my question is that I would like to know how a command is executed with and without `bash -c` in shell. Such information is part of what can help me think about my previous questions https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261595/do-a-bash-script-and-bash-c-command-run-in-a-subshell-environment, and [Why are non-environment variables passed to the subshell invoqued by command substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261402/why-are-non-environment-variables-passed-to-the-subshell-invoqued-by-command-sub)

The following  is a way that I try to understand the above question via `strace`. But you can explain the difference without using `strace`.

I consider two cases, running `bash -c date` and running `bash -c 'date&'`.

1. When I run `bash -c date` in bash shell with pid 6913, and trace the
   shell in another shell:

   ```
   $ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
   Process 6913 attached
   clone(Process 13010 attached
   child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 13010
   [pid  6913] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
   [pid 13010] execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   [pid 13010] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f920c591740) = 0
   [pid 13010] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   [pid 13010] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f67e34df740) = 0
   [pid 13010] exit_group(0)               = ?
   [pid 13010] +++ exited with 0 +++
   <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 13010
   --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13010, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
   wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6781518, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
   ```

   Compared to running `date`in bash shell (see below), is the
   difference only that here we have one more line between the first
   `clone()` and the `execve()` `date`:

   ```
   execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   ```

   What does the difference mean?

   Tracing output of running `date` instead of `bash -c date`:

   ```
   $ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
   [sudo] password for t: 
   Process 6913 attached
   clone(Process 12918 attached
   child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 12918
   [pid  6913] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
   [pid 12918] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   [pid 12918] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff00c632740) = 0
   [pid 12918] exit_group(0)               = ?
   [pid 12918] +++ exited with 0 +++
   <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 12918
   --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12918, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
   wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6781518, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
   ```
2. When I run `bash -c 'date&'` in bash shell with pid 6913, and trace
   the shell in another shell:

   ```
   $ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
   Process 6913 attached
   clone(Process 13023 attached
   child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 13023
   [pid  6913] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
   [pid 13023] execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "date&"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   [pid 13023] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f154970b740) = 0
   [pid 13023] clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,child_tidptr=0x7f154970ba10) = 13024
   [pid 13023] exit_group(0)               = ?
   [pid 13023] +++ exited with 0 +++
   <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 13023
   --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13023, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
   wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6781518, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
   Process 13024 attached
   [pid 13024] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   [pid 13024] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f8045f35740) = 0
   [pid 13024] exit_group(0)               = ?
   [pid 13024] +++ exited with 0 +++
   ```

   Compared to running `date&` in bash shell (see below), the
   difference seems not just having one extra `execve`:

   ```
   execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "date&"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   ```

   but also arrangement of creation of subprocesses,  which subprocess
   `execve()` `date` and which subprocess `execve()` `/bin/bash`.

   What does the difference mean?

   Tracing output when running `date&` instead of `bash -c 'date&'`:

   ```
   $ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
   Process 6913 attached
   clone(Process 12931 attached
   child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 12931
   [pid 12931] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
   [pid 12931] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f530c5ee740) = 0
   [pid 12931] exit_group(0)               = ?
   [pid 12931] +++ exited with 0 +++
   --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12931, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
   wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 12931
   wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6780718, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
   ```

Comment: You seem to know a heckuva lot about the system, so I'm not sure where you are coming from with the question. The answer on the face of it is that 'bash -c date' is asking a new instance of bash to run date, whereas 'date' alone runs it without the extra shell.

Comment: Are you asking what the advantage is of either approach?

Comment: I am asking how a command is executed with and without `bash -c` in shell. Part of the Information that can help to answer my previous questions http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261595/do-a-bash-script-and-bash-c-command-run-in-a-subshell-environment, and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261402/why-are-non-environment-variables-passed-to-the-subshell-invoqued-by-command-sub

Comment: The clone lines are where the action is. There is an untraced clone wherein the subshell execve's data.

But really, that's it. Bash->date or bash->bash->date.