# Isn't a subshell created when I run the `bash` command?

Tags: bash, subshell

Isn't a subshell created when I run the `bash` command? For example, after executing `bash`, I cannot access the value of a non-exported variable. In this case, is the environment I switch to with the bash command not a subshell running under the current bash shell?

```
:~$ value="testing"
:~$ echo $value
testing
:~$ bash
:~$ ps f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
   82 tty1     S      0:00 -bash
   97 tty1     S      0:00  \_ bash
  124 tty1     R      0:00     \_ ps f
:~$
:~$ echo $value
:~$ exit
exit
:~$ export value
:~$ bash
:~$ echo $value
testing
:~$
```

Comment: Are you referring to some specific definition or description of "subshell"? Maybe seen in some other Q/A on this site, or in a man page, or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that isn't a subshell. Subshells in bash are marked using the `BASH_SUBSHELL` variable. This is incremented by 1 for each level of subshell:

```
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL 
0
$ ( echo $BASH_SUBSHELL )
1
$ ( ( echo $BASH_SUBSHELL ) )
2
$ ( ( ( echo $BASH_SUBSHELL ) ) )
3
$ ( ( ( ( echo $BASH_SUBSHELL ) ) ) )
4
$ ( ( ( ( ( echo $BASH_SUBSHELL ) ) ) ) )
5
```

But, this variable doesn't change if you just launch another shell:

```
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL 
0
$ bash
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL 
0
```

This is because when you run a new bash shell, this is a fully new instance. Yes, exported variables will be inherited because this is a *child* shell of your original bash instance, but as you can see above, it isn't actually a subshell of it. Note that subshells inherit all variables, not only the exported ones:

```
$ foo=var
$ ( echo $BASH_SUBSHELL; echo $foo )
1
var
$ bash
$ echo $var ## <-- prints an empty line
```

This is also explained in the `COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT` of `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> Command  substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
> asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment **that
> is a duplicate of the shell environment**, except that traps caught by
> the shell are reset to the values  that the  shell  inherited from
> its parent at invocation.  Builtin commands that are invoked as part
> of a pipeline are also    executed in a subshell environment.  Changes
> made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell's execution
> environment.

So, subshell environments are almost exact duplicates of their parent shells, and that includes all variables, not only exported ones.

Comment: From Bash manual: "A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators | or |&." "Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)." From that, I would believe that `bash` is executed in a subshell. So I'm still confused. But your arguments in the answer seem pretty convincing. (Sorry if I'm being a bit slow, I'm giving my best :)

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes, `bash` is executed _in a subshell_. The `bash` process is not a subshell though. To make the subshell that the `bash` process is running in explicitly visible, think `(bash)`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah, that's it! So the answer to the title is yes, a subshell is created.

Comment: @Quasímodo _In a sense_ which is not usable in a practical sort of way, yes. That subshell exits with the `bash` command terminating. What the user in the question is expecting seems to be that the `bash` instance is a "subshell" of the initial `bash` process, which it isn't. It is however running in a subshell, as a child process. As a child process, it does not have access to un-exported variables.

Comment: Bash doesn't always increment `BASH_SUBSHELL` in subshells: `bash -c 'echo $BASH_SUBSHELL >&2 | echo $BASH_SUBSHELL'`. And yes, those are subshells, acccording both to bash's manpage. (The right hand side of a pipeline may not be a subshell in ksh, etc, but in bash it is; the left hand side is a subshell everywhere).

Comment: And this answer is confusing and wrong in general; When bash runs an external command like `bash` or `cat`, it *does* create a subshell, but that subshell is immediately executing another program, and so the process stops being a subshell. It's the very same thing it happens in a command like `(cat)`.

Comment: @ktzap yes, but (at least as far as I can understand) when you are in the shell created by running `bash` from within another `bash` instance, then you are not in a "subshell" as bash defines it. Yes, the second `bash` instance may be technically running in a subshell as far as the parent bash instance is concerned, but as far as the user of the shell is concerned, this is a separate process, that just happens to be a child shell of the original instance. I think much of the problem here comes down to exactly how you define "subshell" and "child shell".

Comment: @Quasímodo The Bash manual is not as rigorous as the POSIX specification and it may be read as saying that a simple command, being a single-command pipeline, is executed in a subshell. However, this can't obviously be true because both the standard and the Bash manual clearly state that "Changes made to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell’s execution environment". Running simple commands in subshells would make changing directory or doing variable assignment impossible.

Comment: @ commenters: While it may be true that creating a subshell execution environment is equivalent to the forking part in the creation of a separate execution environment, and that a subshell implies a fork in Bash, IMO assuming that any separate process implies a subshell is not really helpful. It'd be better to focus on the abstraction: a subshell environment relates to shell syntax constructs (parentheses, multi-command pipelines, command substitutions, ...) while a separate environment relates to a command being (implemented as) external or not.

Comment: (Sorry for the long commentary, I'm totally fine with it being removed.) Finally, it may be worth mentioning, in this answer, the apparently erratic behavior of `BASH_SUBSHELL`. For example: `echo $BASH_SUBSHELL | cat` prints `0` (not expected), `{ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL; }` prints `0` (expected), but `{ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL; } | cat` prints `1` (expected), showing that `BASH_SUBSHELL` is incremented in pipelines too, just... not always.

Comment: @fra-san Indeed, that quote in the Bash manual should probably only address external commands, since builtin commands do not spawn a subshell, as is stated later in the manual. I think the manual is a bit to blame on making such a generalistic statement without caution.

Comment: @Quasímodo No, _"Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process"_ should not refer to external commands, it should say _"in a multi-command pipeline"_. Builtin commands in a multi-command pipeline are run in their own subshells (try `strace -e clone,execve -f bash -c 'echo foo | :'`: you will see two forks, exactly as with `strace -e clone,execve -f bash -c '/bin/echo foo | /bin/cat'`, just without the `execve` part).

Comment: @fra-san Yes, whereas built-in commands in a simple command (not a multi-command pipeline) is executed by the current shell. That is what I was trying to say, but said it wrong, sorry. Saying this too is important, because saying what spawns a subshell does not automatically say what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Command execution environment section of [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html):

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be
> executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that
> consists of the following.  Unless otherwise noted, the values are
> inherited from the shell.
>
> - shell variables and functions **marked for export**, along with
>   variables exported for the command, passed in the environment

Thus:

- `bash`, not being a builtin or shell function, is executed in a subshell.
- It inherits variables marked for export from its parent shell.
- Only when `value` is exported does the `bash` subshell get it, as your experiments showed.

That does not mean the `bash` shell you get is a subshell, but that it was executed
from a subshell, replacing it, so that the subshell involved is short-lived and is
only a middleman.

See the diagram below.

[image]

<sup>Diagram made with [Dia](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dia/)</sup>

You type `bash` and this forks the current shell, creating an identical one. The yellow sibling waits for the orange one, which `exec`s `bash`. This would happen to any non-builtin command (`zsh`, `g++`, `firefox`...), not only `bash`. All the environment variables are inherited, but since `value` is not one of those and was not exported, the blue Bash does not receive it.

Sources:

- [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html).
- [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261661) to "Is a sub-shell the same thing as a child-shell?"
- [Cuonglm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261406) to "Why are non-environment variables passed to the subshell invoqued by command substitution?"
- Comment section of [Terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/614825).

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a great summary and resource.